# How to create a mock SOAP web service using Python without SoapUI

Tags: python, testing, soap, mocking, wsdl

I need to test a client application which posts data to a SOAP webservice. I am using [zeep](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/) library in my client application to make the SOAP calls. Our test environment is an Ubuntu VM which doesn't have any internet connectivity. I am looking for some way to create a mock SOAP web server in order to test out my client.

So far, I have come across SoapUI, but I will be unable to install it on the test VM. So is there any other way, preferably in python, to mock the SOAP server from a WSDL file so that I can test my client?